# Can not delete a nuget package with the dotnet cli

Tags: .net, nuget, command-line-interface, nuget-package, csproj

I can not delete a nuget package with the dotnet cli.

Here is the command I am running:

> dotnet nuget delete package AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection 7.0.0

Here is the error I am getting:

> error: Source parameter was not specified.

[image]

Here is my `.csproj` file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="7.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Braintree" Version="4.17.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="BraintreeHttp-Dotnet" Version="0.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="3.1.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.1.3">
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.5.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL" Version="3.1.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="PayPalCheckoutSdk" Version="1.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="PayPalHttp" Version="1.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.5.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: you should have a look at `nuget.config` file for package sources

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, I do not have such a file. I have create my project with the help of `dotnet new webapi`.

Comment: as far as I understand you are looking for https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-remove-package dotnet remove package, to remve it from CSPROj, right?  dotnet nuget delete package removes it from server

Comment: @KrzysiekSzymczak, the `dotnet remove pacakage` command is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov should I post my answer in answer or you will close this one as resolved?

Comment: @KrzysiekSzymczak, yes. You should. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see, you are looking for `dotnet remove package` [(docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-remove-package) to remove package from CSPROJ, while `dotnet nuget delete package` [(source)](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-nuget-delete) removes it from nuget server (that's why you need to specify source)

Answer (score 1):

This should be the command

```
dotnet remove package YourPackageName
```

Note there should be no version in there. So the following will not work.

```
 dotnet remove package YourPackageName --version 1.0.0
```

If you include the version, then you will get the following error.

> Specify only one package reference to remove.